# C# - How to use a interface for a generic list when serializing

Tags: c#

I have a generic list say and I want to serialize it.
I want to use a interface for the generic list which can't be serialized
so you have to use the instance. Like this
MyClass implements IMyClass.

```
List<IMyClass> list = DeserializeMyClass(path);    //Can't do this right
```

So have to do this

```
List<MyClass> list = DeserializeMyClass(path);
```

So question is can i now cast to

```
List<IMyClass> ilist = (IMyClass)list;
```

Malcolm

Answer (score 4):

This will work, but I'm not sure it's the best way:

```
List<Test> list = new List<Test>();
List<ITest> ilist = list.ConvertAll<ITest>(x => (ITest)x);
```

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be running in to the fact that C# 3.0 lacks co- and contra-variance.

You probably want to use:

```
list.Cast<IMayClass>().ToList();
```

Comment: This however, returns an IEnumerable, not a List, so it isn't really compatible with assigning to a List<T> like he wants. Of course that's entirely viable if you don't actually need a List.

Answer (score 1):

you can serialize and deserialize interfaces with the BinaryFormatter, but this is not Xml serialization...
What you described is exactly what I need. in addition all my concrete classes are generic..
I have :
IMyInterface interface
MyConcreteClass1 class
MyConcreteClass2 class

and I also have to serialize a collection of such objects (List), with Xml serialization...
looks like it is impossible!

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what it should have been:

```
Listl<IMyclass> list = DeserializeMyClass(path); //Can't do this right
```

So have to do this:

```
List<MyClass> list = DeserializeMyClass(path);
```

So question is can i now cast to:

```
List<IMyclass> ilist = (IMyClass)list;
```

Comment: you can't cast a list to an interface, you are not mapping the collection members there.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but for those that are looking for an answer here is how you can do this is .NET v4

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

    namespace ConsoleApplication6
    {
        internal class Program
        {
            private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                List<ImyInterface> list = new List<ImyInterface>();

                list.Add(new MyClass {MyData = "Test1", SpecialData = "special"});
                list.Add(new MyOtherClass {MyData = "Test2", OtherData = "other"});

                Serialize("c:\\test.dat", list);
                List<ImyInterface> theList = Deserialize<List<ImyInterface>>("c:\\test.dat");
            }

            public static void Serialize<T>(string filename, T objectToSerialize)
            {
                Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
                BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                bFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
                stream.Close();
            }

            public static T Deserialize<T>(string filename)
            {
                Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
                BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                T objectToSerialize = (T) bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
                stream.Close();
                return objectToSerialize;
            }
        }

        public interface ImyInterface
        {
            string MyData { get; set; }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class MyClass : ImyInterface
        {
            public string MyData { get; set; }
            public string SpecialData { get; set; }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class MyOtherClass : ImyInterface
        {
            public string MyData { get; set; }
            public string OtherData { get; set; }
        }
    }
```